# security updates and software updates

Tags: updates, security

hi i am very new to elementary os and interested how secure the os for using with my everyday purchasing. also how often are security updates and software updates are applied to the os.

many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Dave, Elementary os is very secure, all the security updates are passed on as soon as they are released, Linux in general is more secure than windows.
But please remember to still be safe on the net, don't go to risky sites.

Jeff